# Sqlite3 Order By relevance to the input

Tags: python, sqlite

```
    c = conn.cursor()
    search = "SELECT * FROM chavacanowords WHERE filipinoword = ? OR filipinoword = ? OR filipinoword LIKE ? OR filipinoword LIKE ?"
    c.execute(search, ('%'+i+'%', '%'+i.title()+'%', '%'+i+'%', '%'+i.title()+'%'))
    result = c.fetchone()
    if result:
      translatedwords.append(result[0])
    else:
      translatedwords.append(i)
```

I'm trying to match the words input by the user. However, the c.fecthone() gets the earliest entry in on the database.

User Input: Sara

Database: (Sabroso, Sarap) (Trangka, Sara)

Translation: Sabroso (since Sabroso was on the database first than the Trangka)

I'm trying to filter out all of the exact entries by "filipinoword = ? OR filipinoword = ?" and trying to search for resemblance if the exact match doesn't exist "filipinoword LIKE ? or filipinoword LIKE ?"

How can I do it in a way where the exact match comes first and if none then proceed to the LIKE part?

Comment: If there's no exact match, how many similar words do you want to fetch? e.g. if `Database: (Sabroso, Sarap) (Trangka, Sara)` and `User Input: Sar` do you want to return both `Sabroso` and `Trangka` or just `Sabroso` (since it is first)?

Comment: For exact matches (`filipinoword = ?`) you should not add `%` around the input string i.e. you should write `c.execute(search, (i, i.title(), '%'+i+'%', '%'+i.title()+'%'))`

Comment: If there is no exact match I wouldn't mind whatever comes first, however when there is an exact match
User Input: Sara,  
Database: (Sabroso, Sarap) (Trangka, Sara),  I would like for (Trangka, Sara ) to be selected instead of sabroso. I did c.execute(search, (i, i.title(), '%'+i+'%', '%'+i.title()+'%')) and still sabroso is coming out.

Comment: What is `i` and what is `i.title()`?

Comment: I'm iterating through a list (splitted from the user's respose) and I used ``` for i in temptext``` therefore it refers to the word being searched. i.title() is just the word being uppercased on it's first letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your query to use a `UNION` of two queries, with the first looking for an exact match and the second an inexact one. A flag is used to determine whether the match is exact or not and the results sorted by that flag. For example:

```sql
SELECT translation, filipinoword
FROM (
  SELECT *, 1 AS exactmatch
  FROM chavacanowords 
  WHERE filipinoword = 'sara' OR filipinoword = 'Sara'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, 0 AS exactmatch
  FROM chavacanowords 
  WHERE filipinoword LIKE '%sara%' OR filipinoword LIKE '%Sara%'
) m
ORDER BY exactmatch DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dDG3qnJhnJX1QntLMdAg9Z/0)

The sorting ensures that if an exact match is present, it is the value returned.

For python purposes you would replace the strings in the `WHERE` clause with `?` and pass them as parameters i.e.

```py
search = "SELECT translation, filipinoword \
FROM ( \
  SELECT *, 1 AS exactmatch \
  FROM chavacanowords \
  WHERE filipinoword = ? OR filipinoword = ? \
  UNION ALL \
  SELECT *, 0 AS exactmatch \
  FROM chavacanowords \
  WHERE filipinoword LIKE ? OR filipinoword LIKE ? \
) m \
ORDER BY exactmatch DESC \
LIMIT 1"
c.execute(search, (i, i.title(), '%'+i+'%', '%'+i.title()+'%'))
```